# Delete all other undefined directories

Tags: shell-script, find, directory, ksh, rm

I need to create a purge script to remove any foreign directories from a specific list of directories.

My idee was to do something like this :

```
 #!/bin/ksh find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'SE' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Rejet' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Acq' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Archiv' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Cloture' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Emis' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Ident' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Irr*' | find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d ! -name 'Recep*'
```

and then `-type f -exec rm {} \;` but don't really know how to do this.

Comment: Which directories and/or directory paths do you want to delete? (Please [update your question to include this information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/392169/edit) as if you'd included it originally, so I can then delete this comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all folders within path `/data/${USER}/SAS/` except those are in predefined/specified list - use the following optimized `find` approach:

```
find /data/${USER}/SAS/ -type d -regextype posix-egrep \
    ! -regex ".*/(SE|Rejet|Acq|Archiv|Cloture|Emis|Ident|Irr.*|Recep.*)" \
    ! -name "SAS" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `ksh`, it should just be a matter of:

```
(FIGNORE='@(.|..)'; cd /data/"$USER"/SAS/ && 
   echo rm -rf -- !(SE|Rejet|Acq|Archiv|Cloture|Emis|Ident|Irr*|Recep*)/)
```

(remove `echo` when happy)

Which would remove all the directories except those that match that list (leaving the non-directory files alone).

Remove the `FIGNORE` part if  you don't want to remove hidden directories.

Note that it will also consider symlinks to directories (and depending on the `rm` implementation either delete the symlink or the *content* of the target).

With `find`, you'd do:

```
cd /data/"$USER"/SAS &&
  find . ! -name . -prune \
    ! -name SE \
    ! -name Reject \
    ! -name Acq \
    ! -name Archiv \
    ! -name Cloture \
    ! -name Emis \
    ! -name Ident \
    ! -name 'Irr*' \
    ! -name 'Recep*' -type d -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```